# ¿es posible cargar archivos .json de traducciones en producción con vue i18n y laravel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, i18n

He creado un sistema donde puedo editar las traducciones y generar nuevas traducciones personalizadas, donde genero un archivo JSON. el problema está que ala hora de generar el archivo en producción y trato de obtener con `requere.context` de Webpack no lo reconoce sino hasta que recompilo el proyecto.

Aquí muestro como tengo configurado la carga de los lenguajes.

i18n.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const loadedLanguages = [] 
const langs = loadFiles();

const messages = {};

Object.keys(langs).forEach(key => {
    messages[key] = { ...messages[key], ...langs[key] }
});

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'es',
    messages,
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
});

function loadFiles() {
   //cargo los archivos de traducciones generados
    const context = require.context('../../../public/storage/langs', true, /.json$/, 'sync');
    const all = {};
    context.keys().forEach((key) => {
        const fileName = key.replace('./', '');
        const resource = require(`../../../public/storage/langs/${fileName}`);
        const namespace = fileName.replace('.json', '');
        all[namespace] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resource));
         //guardo todos los nombres de las traducciones cargados
        loadedLanguages.push(namespace)
    });
    return all
}

function setI18nLanguage (lang) {
    i18n.locale = lang
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = lang
    document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', lang)
    return lang
}

const loadLanguageAsync = async (lang) => {
    if (i18n.locale === lang) {
        return Promise.resolve(setI18nLanguage(lang))
    }

    if (loadedLanguages.includes(lang)) {
        return Promise.resolve(setI18nLanguage(lang))
    }
    //Si no está el lenguage cargado se vuelven a cargar todos los lenguajes(.json) 
    loadFiles()
    //retorna el objeto con todos los lenguajes cargados
    return Promise.resolve(setI18nLanguage(lang))
}

export { i18n, loadLanguageAsync };
```

De esta manera hago el llamado en cada formulario para cambiar el idioma que se le asignó a ese eformulario.

form.vue

```
loadLanguageAsync(this.form_structure.lang.code).then(() => {
            console.log('terminó');
        })
```

Si los archivos están compilados funciona perfectamente, pero si quiero crear un nuevo .JSON personalizado no lo reconoce `require.context` y solo me muestra los que ya están siendo compilado.

```
const context = require.context('../../../public/storage/langs', true, /.json$/, 'sync');
```

Puede ser alguna configuración de Webpack u otro método de cargar los archivos.

Estoy utilizando:

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"laravel-mix": "^6.0.49"
"vue": "^2.6.4",
"vue-i18n": "^8.22.0",
"webpack": "^5.0.0",
```

me he guiado en la documentación Lazy loading translations pero aún no funciona
https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html

Mi objetivo es lograr cargar archivos JSON en caliente, ya sea con Webpack o algún otro medio que los pueda reconocer i18n y posteriormente utilizarlos.

Agradezco antemano cualquier comentario o sugerencia, muchas gracias.

Comment: fijate si son los magic comments https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import ahi le podes decir como carga o bundlea

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Ya he intentado con este método, pero a la hora de generar el JSON y tratar de importarlo me sale el siguiente error: `form.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './lazy.json'`